# enumerate with description and label for reference

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, description

I want to create an enumerated list with description of items and a label assigned so that each item can individually be referenced by `\ref` or `\nameref`

It is obvious how to do this manually but I would like to save myself a bit of work and create some commands to have latex do the job

This is the LaTeX code I want to atomise

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{T\,\arabic*},leftmargin=1cm]
\item \textit{caption} \label{itm:1}
\end{enumerate}
```

now I would like to reference the label like this

```
\ref{itm:1}
>> T1
\nameref{itm:1}
>> (T1) caption
```

referencing subsequent items accordingly by increasing the counter

any idea / help is highly appreciated

Comment: `\item` does increase the counter, that is true, but it does not care about the following text afterwards!

Comment: Will *all* items have both a number and a description?

Comment: yes. all items will have a number and a description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a wrapper command `\myitem` to grab the item text and stores it into `\@currentlabelname`, which is needed by `\nameref` to use the 'name' properly!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myitem}[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
  \item #2%
  }{%
  \item[#1] #2%
  }%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{(\theenumi) #2}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{T\,\arabic*},leftmargin=1cm]
\myitem{\textit{caption}} \label{itm:1}
\myitem{Some other important text} \label{itm:2}
\end{enumerate}

Now, we use \nameref{itm:1} and \ref{itm:1}

And \nameref{itm:2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** -- With automatic labelling, be careful on reset on the enumerate list!

The `Ti1` is the first label of the first level of an enumerate, the `Tii1`, `Tiii1` and `Tiv1` will be the relevant labels of deeper levels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}




\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myitem}[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
  \item #2%
  }{%
  \item[#1] #2%
  }%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{(\csname the\@enumctr\endcsname) #2}
  \label{T\romannumeral\@enumdepth\arabic{\@enumctr}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{T\,\arabic*},leftmargin=1cm]
\myitem{\textit{caption}}
\myitem{Some other important text}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Foooo\arabic*}]
  \myitem{\textbf{Subitem}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\clearpage
Now, we use \nameref{Ti1} and \ref{Ti1}

And \nameref{Ti2} or \nameref{Tii1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: amazing. thank you. Would be also possible to integrate the label command with your new command and make use of the item counter? that way you won't have to maintain the labels and label counts by hand. the `\label{}` for reference would then be the same as the printed version in the list.so that if there is a list item T1 caption you could reference it with `\ref{T1}` without manually defining `\label{T1}`

Comment: @Martin: Possible, but not recommended.

Comment: @Martin: the problem with generating a label by `T1` etc. is that the item label will be reset in a new `\begin{enumerate}` unless you use the `resume` option!

Comment: I will provide a way that takes the level of enumeration also into account!

Comment: @Martin: see the update at the bottom please!

Comment: @Martin: Well, I don't recommend it actually. If the resetting will become an issue, another strategy must be used!